# How to perform a search using pg search gem for a field that is assoicatied through another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg-search

I have a table called user and I just created a tagging system, where users can have tags through another table.
[Same way this rail cast does it for it's Books and Authors.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised)

Now I have a search already which is based this way:

```
def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      where("first_name @@ :q OR last_name @@ :q OR country @@ :q OR (first_name || ' ' || last_name) @@ :q", :q => query)
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

if I don't have a field inside the user table to search for it, any one can suggest me a join search ?
I just can't figure out the syntax with pg_search

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gem called [Texticle](https://github.com/ecin/texticle) , and here is an awesome [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql?autoplay=true) about it!
Check it out! It does the job well!